# JavaScript - Converting a Date() into seconds

Tags: javascript, date, time, algolia, hacker-news-api

I'm using the Hacker News API made at Algolia here:

https://hn.algolia.com/api

I'm a bit confused as it says to search for posts since a certain time it says to run the following query:

Comments since timestamp `X` (in second)
`http://hn.algolia.com/api/v1/search_by_date?tags=comment&numericFilters=created_at_i>X`

It says to replace `X` with a timestamp in seconds, but how exactly would you do this? Let's say the last post I have is at `2015-08-25T15:35:58.000Z`. How exactly would I run this query to search for posts since that date? I don't know how to convert this date to seconds...

Answer (score 90, accepted):

`getTime()` will get the date in milliseconds, so divide by 1000:

```
var date = new Date("2015-08-25T15:35:58.000Z");
var seconds = date.getTime() / 1000; //1440516958
```

Comment: in some cases, you may want to add rounding. `Math.round(...)`

Comment: @IonicMan, welcome to SO. What did you `try`, what did you `expect`?

Comment: `Math.round(Date.now() / 1000)` - shorter and about twice as performant