# Get only seconds from the current date in React.Js component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, date

Hey i want to extract only the seconds from the current date and i am kind of  blocked

**This is my component and it only returns the whole date:**

```
  class Clock extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          time: new Date().toLocaleString()
        };
      }
      componentDidMount() {
        this.intervalID = setInterval(
          () => this.tick(),
          1000
        );
      }
      componentWillUnmount() {
        clearInterval(this.intervalID);
      }
      tick() {
        this.setState({
          time: new Date().toLocaleString()
        });
      }
      render() {
        return (
         <div>{this.state.time}.</div>


        );
      }
     }
  export default Clock;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32208476/javascript-converting-a-date-into-seconds

Comment: i dont want to convert into seconds i just wana extract the current seconds of the current date !

Comment: You can use the getSeconds(); method on the date object

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      time: new Date().getSeconds()
    };
  }
```

You can use the `getSeconds();` method on the date object